# Java upcasting issue

Tags: java

I have a following code

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Parent upCasted = new Child();
        System.out.println("String: " + upCasted.getString());
        System.out.println("Int: " + upCasted.a);
    }
}


class Parent {
    int a = 1;

    public String getString() {
        return "Parent";
    }
}

class Child extends Parent {
    int a = 2;

    @Override
    public String getString() {
        return "Child";
    }
}
```

When I run it I see this in console

```
String: Child
Int: 1
```

Why during the upcasting the `int` value was taken from the `Parent` and the `String` value from the `Child?`

Comment: what "upcasting"? you declared your variable as being of type Parent. there is no casting involved here

Comment: How do expect a primitive type to be overriden?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's because instance fields are not overridden when re-declared in child classes.

Instead, when `upCasted.a` is evaluated, Java looks at the static/declared type of `upCasted` to know which class's field to read (not at the runtime class of the object that `upCasted` points to).

This is why one should not use the same name for fields in superclasses and subclasses.